# Lenovo S10 WiFi connection problems

Tags: troubleshooting, wireless-networking

At home I have an ADSL modem (ZTE ZXDSL 831 C) which is also a router and a WiFi access point. My desktop PC is connected via Ethernet directly to this router, wheras iPhone and Lenovo laptop both connect over WPA-secured WiFi.

While iPhone establishes a very solid connection and pretty much connects as soon as Safari starts up, Lenovo has some weird issues. First, standard Windows Wireless Networks window lists my home network as insecure. Trying to connect to it makes Windows think for a couple of minutes with a generic "Connecting to network" message and then no connection is made.

Occasionally, though, netbook will connect to the network, but the connection is very unstable.

What do I do to troubleshoot this whole issue? As a sidenote, I removed all the Interl PROset crapware from autostart. Can this be a reason or something else is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating to the latest drivers?